# Does the verb "reduce" have an adjective form meaning "can be reduced"?

Tags: adjectives

Some verbs have adjective forms meaning the verb can be done.  For example, "searchable" means "can be searched".  I searched for the adjective form of "reduce" and found the word "reducible".  However, as far I searched, it seems that this word is usually used in the field of chemistry. Does this word "reducible" can be used in general sentences, such as the following:

> The shipping cost is reducible by negotiation.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is grammatical, but hardly idiomatic, since **reducible** is not normally used to mean "can be lowered".  Its usual meaning is "can be simplified".

> The shipping cost is negociable|negotiable.

is the standard idiomatic way to express "a lower price can be negotiated".